# How to access array of dictionaries and use the dictionary objects in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsarray, nsdictionary

This is my "po array" looks like.

```
<__NSArrayI 0x7fe093f87160>(
<Entry: 0x600000498c90> (entity: Entry; id: 30506398-1852-433D-B536- 
DC57F484F754> ; data: {
cumulativeTime = 0000;
latitude = “12.972442”
longitude = "77.580643";
type = enrty;
entryName = Bangalore;
}),
<Entry: 0x600000498c90> (entity: Entry; id: 30506398-1852-433D-B536- 
DC57F484F754> ; data: {
cumulativeTime = 0000;
latitude = “13.067439”
longitude = "80.237617";
type = enrty;
entryName = Chennai;
})
```

The above JSON is stored in and I'm retrieving using the below code.

```
 +(NSArray*) routePlan
{
     NSString* aircraftJSONString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Documents/DataJson" withExtension:nil]

encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray* aircraftJsonFplWaypoints = [aircraftJSONString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
}
```

I can access the array[0] but not the objects in array[0]. I need the latitude and longitude. Any idea how to strip down to the inside dictionary values.

Comment: get array[0] as dictionary than get value of the key from dictionary.

Comment: CAN YOU SHARE SOME CODE?

Comment: This can never be the *array* in the question. By the way: Please don't use the comments to add information. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49530301/edit) your question.

Comment: Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @HirakBarman check my answer

Comment: where you implement this method can you share that code in your question?

Comment: @RealmOfFire I have updated the question. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 2):

The *dictionaries* seem to be instances of an `NSManagedObject` subclass named `Entry`.

Just use a loop to iterate over the entries

```
for (Entry *entry in array) {
    NSLog(@"lat: %@ - long: %@", entry.latitude, entry.longitude);

}
```

Comment: No luck. Still crash.

Comment: You are talking about two **different** things. The `po array` mentioned in the question and the array you got from the JSON string. The former is an array of `Entry` instances and the latter is an array of `String`. There is no dictionary involved. Usually JSON is supposed to be deserialized with `NSJSONSerialization`.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to dev and got stuck on this issue.

Comment: Sorry, the question cannot be answered with the current information. Please add more information for example the JSON and what you are going to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use objective c fast enumeration for getting data from ArrayList.

```
for (NSDictionary *dic in array) {
    NSLog(@"dic values %@",[dic objectForKey:@"data"]);

    NSDictionary *data = [dic objectForKey:@"data"];

    NSString *lat = [data objectForKey:@"latitude"];

}
```

Comment: Does not work. 

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdc427a7ab0'

Comment: @HirakBarman try to get [dic objectForKey:@"data"]. if you are getting then let me know.

Comment: Nope getting crash.

Comment: @HirakBarman can you share source from where  this data is getting or share your code

Comment: @HirakBarman check your array content weather is it properly in JSON format or not. you can use online tools for JSON format validation.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of dictionaries and you need to parse through it.

I haven't tried running this code but this should work. Later on you can add some safety checks for nil values.

```
NSDictionary *dict = array[0];
NSString *latitude = dict["latitude"];
NSString *longitude = dict["longitude"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use key value coding :

```
[array[0] valueForKey:@"latitude"];
```